# Pandas turn column into MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

How do I turn the first column of this `DataFrame` which is mixed strings and integers

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["title1", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [10, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [100, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        ["title2", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [10, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [100, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        ["title3", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [10, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [100, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ]
)
```

looking like this

```
title1  a   b   c   d
1       2   3   4   5
10      2   3   4   5
100     2   3   4   5
title2  a   b   c   d
1       2   3   4   5
10      2   3   4   5
100     2   3   4   5
title3  a   b   c   d
1       2   3   4   5
10      2   3   4   5
100     2   3   4   5
```

into a `MultiIndex` with string in the top level and integers in the second?

```
            a   b   c   d
title1  1   2   3   4   5
        10  2   3   4   5
        100 2   3   4   5
title2  1   2   3   4   5
        10  2   3   4   5
        100 2   3   4   5
title3  1   2   3   4   5
        10  2   3   4   5
        100 2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Are values a,b,c,d in real data same for each row?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, they are identical.

Comment: Super, so answer should working nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#get mask for distingusih strings values in column 0
m = pd.to_numeric(df[0], errors='coerce').isna()
#alternative
#m = ~df[0].astype(str).str.isnumeric()
#create new column 0 filled with strings
df.insert(0, 'a', df[0].where(m).ffill())
#mask for filter not same values in both columns
m1 = df['a'].ne(df[0])
#create MultiIndex
df = df.set_index(['a', 0])
#assign new columns names by first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
#filter out by mask and remove index, columns names
df = df[m1.values].rename_axis((None, None)).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
            a  b  c  d
title1 1    2  3  4  5
       10   2  3  4  5
       100  2  3  4  5
title2 1    2  3  4  5
       10   2  3  4  5
       100  2  3  4  5
title3 1    2  3  4  5
       10   2  3  4  5
       100  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: How can I name the two index columns to display, say, `i1` above the titles and `i2` above the `[1,10,100]`?

Comment: @Casimir - change `.rename_axis((None, None))` to `.rename_axis(('i1', 'i2'))`

Answer (score 1):

The key to this type of issues is to create a boolean series identifying the location of level_0 index,

```
mask = df[1].str.contains('a')   # Identify the rows containing the level_0 multiindex

header = df.loc[0,1:4].to_list()   # Get header list

df[-1] = df[0].where(mask).ffill()   # Create a seperate level_0 column

result = (df[~mask.fillna(False)]
            .set_index([-1,0])
            .astype(int)
            .rename_axis([None,None])
            .set_axis(header,axis=1,inplace=False))
```